# Could a gyroscope demonstrate absolute motion?

Tags: reference-frames, relative-motion, gyroscopes

If a spaceship were moving very fast, and a rocket motor mounted perpendicular to the direction of motion/"main thruster" were turned on, the change in direction to an observer would be proportional to the power of the rocket motor. But an astronaut inside the ship without a gyroscope would only notice sideways acceleration. However, would the gyroscope not indicate to the astronaut that the ship had changed direction and therefore imply that the ship had been in motion prior to the application of the perpendicular rocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a rocket ship is coasting along and then a side thruster is turned on, then (1) in one case you're assuming that it causes an acceleration in the perpendicular direction AND it also rotates the nose of the rocket into a direction consistent with velocity vector of the rocket as seen by some fixed observer. However, in the other case (2) you're assuming that the side thruster merely accelerates the rocket sideways without any rotation of the rocket.

Of course a gyroscope will detect rotation of the rocket in case (1) but not in case (2). But that's simply because you're assuming that in addition to the sideways acceleration the rocket is also being rotated in case (1), and that rotation is due to some small, additional torque that you're introducing in case (1) but not in case (2).

Comment: Doesn't a gyroscope know which way the ship is pointing? I do not mean for the side thruster to cause rotation but to add a component to the ship's velocity that would appear to an outside observer (and perhaps an astronaut aboard the ship with a gyroscope) to change the ship's direction.

Comment: A gyroscope does know which way the ship is pointing. If you don't mean for the side thruster to cause rotation, then what the stationary observer will see when the side-thruster fires is your rocket changing its direction of motion BUT keeping its nose pointing fixed in its original direction. The rocket will appear to the observer to be be sort of 'skidding' sideways to the direction that it is pointing in and the gyroscope will NOT detect any rotation. You tacitly assumed that the rocket's nose always has to be pointing in the direction of motion as observed by the stationary observer.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Indeed, it will slide over while the thruster is on; once it is off, the nose will be pointing in the exact same direction. Not the best question, now that I think of it.

Comment: It was a good question. It pointed out the way that subtle problems can creep in without detection when thinking about relativity. In truth, there is no "natural" direction for a rocket's nose to point in outer space, since if one observer sees the rocket's nose pointing exactly in the direction of its motion then other moving observers will see the rocket's nose pointing in other directions with respect to its direction of motion. On Earth, on the other hand, it's natural for a rocket's nose to always point in its direction of motion because otherwise too large aerodynamic stresses will exist